# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException while running python code

Tags: java, python, pycharm

I am having a strange problems. I am trying to run the language_check package in python 2.7. The package is installed and I am using JRE version 9. 
When I run my code I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
```

I found that I should add a module for newer version of JAVA but I am running the code from pycharm. Can someone help me to fix the problems.

Best

Comment: Have you tried using Java 8 instead of Java 9?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I can say it is because of JRE version. Try to switch to JRE version 8.

Make sure that OS sees version 8 not version 9 when you installed JRE. You can check java version with this command:

```
java -version
```